# where do I get the secret property for creating webhook for azure speech to text service

Tags: python-3.x, azure, webhooks, azure-speech, azure-webhooks

If you look at the properties key,secret value is **SecretUsedToCreateHMACHexDigestThatYouWillFindIn**
where do i get this value from ?

```
{
  "displayName": "TranscriptionCompletionWebHook",
  "properties": {
    "secret": "SecretUsedToCreateHMACHexDigestThatYouWillFindIn\"X-MicrosoftSpeechServices-Signature\"HeaderWhenBeingCalledBack"
  },
  "webUrl": "https://contoso.com/call/me/back",
  "events": {
    "transcriptionCompletion": true
  },
  "description": "I registered this URL to get a POST request for each completed transcription."
}
```

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71081339/azures-speech-to-text-webhook-header-x-microsoftspeechservices-signature-algorit/71859794#71859794), there I described a solution in Python.